# JQuery - do something for both selected and unselected checkboxes

Tags: jquery, select, each

I am able to loop through my selected boxes using:

```
 $('#sel_driver_file_options :selected').each(function(i, selected) { 
                //console.log($(this).val());
                var driverName = $(this).val();
                var driverText = $(this).text();
                $("#tr_file_options_input").show();
                $("#span_" + driverName).show();
                $('<div id="desc_file_options_input_' + driverName + '">Enter a Value For ' + driverText + '</div>').prependTo($("#span_" + driverName));
            }); // end selected each
```

But how do I perform an action on all checkboxes within '#sel_driver_file_options' that are not selected?

What I am trying to do is remove the added:

```
$('<div id="desc_file_options_input_' + driverName + '">Enter a Value For ' + driverText + '</div>').prependTo($("#span_" + driverName));
```

When the user deselects it. Otherwise, if they select it again, it creates a second one.

Edit: [JSFiddle for the full block of code I am working on](http://jsfiddle.net/5x5aK/1/)

Edit2: Updated JSFiddle, Re-wrote the table for better organization, changed the close function to this:

```
close: function (event, ui) {
            $('#sel_driver_file_options :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
                var driverName = $(this).val();
                var driverText = $(this).text();
                var driverSpan = $("#span_" + driverName);
                var driverDesc = $("#desc_" + driverName);
                console.log("Selected = " + driverName);
                $("#tr_file_options_input").show();
                $(driverSpan).show();
                $(driverDesc).show();
            }); // end each selected
            $('#sel_driver_file_options').not(':selected').each(function () {
                //if ($('#sel_driver_file_options').not(':selected')) {
                var driverName = $(this).val();
                var driverText = $(this).text();
                var driverSpan = $("#span_" + driverName);
                var driverDesc = $("#desc_" + driverName);
                console.log("Not Selected = " + driverName);
                $(driverSpan).hide();
                $(driverDesc).hide();
                // driverSpan.find('[id^="desc_file_options_input_"]').remove();
            }); // end each not selected
            //$('#desc_file_options_input_' + driverName).remove();
        } //end close function
```

Now the console shows:

```
Selected = default-priority
Not Selected = default-priority
```

As if the not(':selected') is not working?

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle with the HTML included

Comment: Added a link in the question

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it out by putting the selected into an array and then running .each again and hiding all spans not in the array.
It's working as expected now.
[Here's the JSFiddle for the working solution in case anyone needs it.](http://jsfiddle.net/5x5aK/4/)

And here's the relevant code:

```
$("#sel_driver_file_options").multiselect({
    show: ["blind", 200],
    hide: ["blind", 500],
    multiple: true,
    selectedList: 3,
    noneSelectedText: "Select file() options",
    open: function (event, ui) {
        // nothing for now
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
        var arr = [];
        $('#sel_driver_file_options :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
            var driverName = $(this).val();
            var driverText = $(this).text();
            var driverSpan = $("#span_" + driverName);
            var driverDesc = $("#desc_" + driverName);
            arr.push(driverName);
            console.log("Selected = " + driverName);
            $("#tr_file_options_input").show();
            $(driverSpan).show();
            $(driverDesc).show();
        }); // end each selected
        // Now loop through all options and remove spans for unselected ones
        $('#sel_driver_file_options option').each(function () {
            var driverName = $(this).val();
            var driverText = $(this).text();
            var driverSpan = $("#span_" + driverName);
            var driverDesc = $("#desc_" + driverName);
            if ($.inArray(driverName, arr) == -1) {
                console.log("Not in array: " + driverName);
                $(driverSpan).hide();
                $(driverDesc).hide();
            }
        }); // end each not selected
    } //end close function
}); // end multiselect
```

Answer (score -1):

something like this would work

```
$('#sel_driver_file_options').not(':selected');
```